# jquery - A moving animation for list item when the other's are hidden?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a  grid view with item with image and text in it.

Let's see.... Um, just like this one.

[image: no description, I hate a description, thank you. why image in stackoverflow need a description? huh ?]

It's make by css ul>li{float:left}

Thoes Item is classified by category. the default view is display items from all category.

And when I click on the category link, the item of other category will become {disply:none}.

so, the screen will left the items belong to the category which you click.

what I want to do :

some the items is hide, and other stay in the position before I click, then they are going to moving to the new position in animation.

Comment: set visibility hidden instead of display none...

Comment: Instead of using Display:None , use Hide() method of JQuery. may your problem can be solve by this.

Comment: @KuashalKhamar `hide()` method does the same thing.

Comment: I want the items hold position at like when you use {visibility: hidden}, but that's just the step one. And then the item shall move to target position when is the place when you use {display: none}. And that animation should trigger whenever some function make the item hide.

Comment: @ZittyYam that is really interesting. So can you provide a demo of what do you have so far? Or do you expect the community to do everything from the scratch?

Comment: ok, If i give you a url of jsBin, How can I provide the code is made by me ? Or are you just think this is not a good question for some another reason ?

Answer (score 0):

By setting `display:none` the elements won't be rendered at all hence the other elements position will be re-arranged.

If you want the items to say at it's positions, set `visibility:hidden` instead, so that the elements will be hidden while still occupying their space, avoiding the re-arrangement.

Comment: say at it's positions? that's just the step one. see my question last sentence or my new add comment.